# Postfix MAILER-DAEMON messages

Tags: postfix

I want to configure postfix such that if a message from MAILER-DAEMON is not immediately deliverable, the message should be dropped/discarded rather than be deferred or handed off to my smtp fallback relay.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#bounce_queue_lifetime

This works for locally generated bounces.