# Postfix: Deliver relay failure messages locally, instead over the failed relay

Tags: postfix

**Is it possible to exempt "MAILER DAEMON" messages from alias expansion or relaying?**

Context: Let's illustrate the problem is on this trivial forward-all setup:

```
/etc/aliases
root: monitoring@domain.com

/etc/postfix/generic_maps
@host.local linuxmail@domain.com

/etc/postfix/main.cf
relayhost = [smtp.domain.com]:submission
```

When the relay breaks

- regular cronjob tries to send e-mail From:root@host.local
- it gets rewritten by aliases and encounters relaying failure
- "MAILER DAEMON" sends warning e-mail To:root@host.local
- it gets rewritten by aliases and encounters relaying failure
- the errors uselessly clutter the queue

I'd like them delivered to local inbox, alerting administrators who log in.
How do I exempt the error mail from alias expansion and/or relaying?

Answer (score 1):

**1 Sane solution**

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
   bounce_queue_lifetime = 0
   notify_classes = bounce
   bounce_notice_recipient = bounces@<yourdomain.tld>
```

- You may be tempted to disable bounce(8) service, but *I expect* that disables postmaster bounces.

For more details see the [Drop undelivered MAILER-DAEMON](https://serverfault.com/questions/218336/postfix-mailer-daemon-messages) and [collect bounces in postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/48326/how-to-collect-bounces-in-postfix/735721#735721)

How it works:

1. Undeliverable bounce messages are deleted
2. A copy of all bounce messages is sent to bounces@<yourdomain.tld>

Drawbacks: 1) bounces@<yourdomain.tld> must be a non-redirected local inbox. 2) original bounce messages are deleted *after* the server attempts their useless delivery over the failed relay

**2 Slightly Insane solution (untested)**

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
   sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:sender_dependent_default_transport_maps
   virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
   virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps
   virtual_uid_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_uid_maps
   virtual_gid_maps = static:<GID_of_/var/spool/mail>
   #virtual_mailbox_domains = <yourdomain.tld> #MAYBE
```

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps
   MAILER-DAEMON@<yourdomain.tld> virtual:
```

```
/etc/postfix/virtual_uid_maps
   alice@<yourdomain.tld>   1000
   bob@<yourdomain.tld>     1002
   charlie@<yourdomain.tld> 1001
```

```
/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps
   alice@<yourdomain.tld>    alice/
   bob@<yourdomain.tld>      bob
   charlie@<yourdomain.tld>  charlie
```

- Don't forget to $postmap all *_maps files after every change.

For more details see the [virtual delivery agent manpage](http://www.postfix.org/virtual.8.html) and [collect bounces in postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/48326/how-to-collect-bounces-in-postfix/735721#735721)

How it works:

1. sender_dependent_default_transport_maps forces bounce delivery by virtual: delivery agent ...
2. ... which delivers the message to mailbox/maildir configured in virtual_*_maps

Drawbacks: 1) Untested. 2) Will never deliver to UID below virtual_minimum_uid. 3) virtual_*_maps must be manually kept in sync with existing user accounts

**3 fully Insane solution**

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf
   virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail
   virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps
   virtual_uid_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual_uid_maps
   virtual_gid_maps = static:<GID_of_/var/spool/mail>
   virtual_mailbox_domains = bounces.<yourdomain.tld>
   smtp_generic_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/generic_maps
   sender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/canonical_sender_maps
```

```
/etc/postfix/virtual_uid_maps
   alice@bounces.<yourdomain.tld>   1000
   bob@bounces.<yourdomain.tld>     1002
   charlie@bounces.<yourdomain.tld> 1001
```

```
/etc/postfix/virtual_mailbox_maps
   alice@bounces.<yourdomain.tld>    alice/
   bob@bounces.<yourdomain.tld>      bob
   charlie@bounces.<yourdomain.tld>  charlie
```

```
/etc/postfix/generic_maps
   /@bounces./ @
```

```
/etc/postfix/canonical_sender_maps
   /^([^@]*)$/ $(1)@bounces.<yourdomain.tld>
   /^([^@]*)@/ $(1)@bounces.
```

- Don't forget to $postmap all *_maps files after every change.

How it works:

1. canonical_sender_maps adds "bounces." to *senders* of all locally queued mail
2. If a message goes out by SMTP, smtp_generic_maps undoes the change
3. If a message bounces, smtp_generic_maps does not apply ...
4. ... and notification is delivered to virtual domain @bounces.<yourdomain.tld>...
5. ... which delivers the message to mailbox/maildir configured in virtual_*_maps

For more details see the [address rewriting overview](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#overview)

Drawbacks: 1) Insane. 2) Will never deliver to UID below virtual_minimum_uid 3) virtual_*_maps must be manually kept in sync with existing user accounts